# Ansible: The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines', but changing `stdout_lines` to `results` does not solve the problem

Tags: python, bash, dictionary, ansible

I am a beginner with ansible.

I have copied a playbook managed by third parts and extended into the following one, then I run it in debug mode (`-vvv`) via

```
/home/.../ansible-venv/bin/ansible-playbook -vvv playbooks/dump_data_into_csv.yml >/dump_data_into_csv.log 2>&1
```

The playbook runs fine when the snippet

```
- hosts: myhosts
# - hosts: 
#     - myhost-010_c1
#     - myhost-010_c3
#     - myhost-014_c4
```

is uncommented and the snippet

```
- hosts: myhosts
```

is commented.

When the case is the opposite, as you can read in the following code, running the playbook raises this error:

```
Dump data to csv...

  host-001_c1 failed: {

    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/.../dump_data_into_csv.yml': line 64, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Dump data to csv\n      ^ here\n"

}
```

where "line 64, column 7" is indicated by my comment into the playbook below.

I have searched on the internet this message

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'

and from what I read on [this article](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-dict-object-has-no-attribute-stdout-or-stderr-how-to-resolve/#Why_this_error) I understand that this error is raised when one tries to access the `stdout_lines` object of a dictionary, which does not have that object, and which instead has the object `results`.

So I have substituted in my playbook

```
{% if host.grep_output.stdout_lines %}
{% for line in host.grep_output.stdout_lines %}
```

with

```
{% if host.grep_output.results %}
{% for line in host.grep_output.results %}
```

but the error shows up again.

What am I doing wrong?

```
- hosts: myhosts
# - hosts: 
#     - myhost-010_c1
#     - myhost-010_c3
#     - myhost-014_c4
    
  order: sorted
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    current_date: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Grep over syslog
      become: true
      ansible.builtin.shell:          
        cmd: |
          tomorrow_date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d "$input_date + 1 day")
          six_days_ago_date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d "$input_date - 6 days")      

          last_seven_days_syslogs=$(find /var/log/ -type f -name "syslog*" -newermt "$six_days_ago_date" ! -newermt "$tomorrow_date" | sort)

          sudo zgrep -aHF "my_pattern" $last_seven_days_syslogs | cut -d'[' -f 1

      register: grep_output
      ignore_errors: true
      no_log: true


    - name: Dump data to csv
    #  ^ this is  line 64, column 7
      copy:
        dest: /tmp/data_{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime }}.csv
        content: |
          {{ ['idm', 'idc', 'mese', 'giorno', 'orario'] | map('trim') | join(';') }}
          {% for host in hosts_list %}
          {% set idm = host.inventory_hostname.split('_')[0].split('-')[1] %}
          {% set idm_padded = '%03d' % idm|int %}
          {% set idm_padded = '"' + idm_padded + '"' %}
          {% set idc = host.inventory_hostname.split('_')[1].upper() %}
          {% if host.grep_output.stdout_lines %}
          {% for line in host.grep_output.stdout_lines %}
          {% set month = line.strip().split(':')[1].replace('  ', ' ').split(' ')[0] %}
          {% set day = line.strip().replace('  ', ' ').split(' ')[1] %}
          {% set time = line.strip().replace('  ', ' ').split(' ')[2] %}
          {{ [idm_padded, idc, month, day, time] | map('trim') | join(';') }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          
      vars:
        hosts_list: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars) | list }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: csv_content
      run_once: yes
```

Comment: You will have a `results` property in your dictionary only if the register was made with a loop, which is not your case here, so you are looking in the wrong direction. Debug the `grep_output`, I am pretty sure you will see it actually failed (`grep` returns a non-zero code when there is no match), and this is why you do not have `stdout_lines`.

Comment: All this said, you should look into using the proper Ansible modules instead of raw shell like this. The module [`find`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Since you use `ignore_errors: true` on your shell task, ansible will not stop on error but chances are `stdout_lines` does not exist in your registered var in that case.